# Hazel rule using Python script

Tags: macos, python

I am using a Hazel (Noodlesoft) rule with Python script.   Using the "Passes Shell script" option.   Placing the path to my python install /usr/local/bin/python (my python install v. 2.7.3) in the shell box.   Correctly goes to plack if it finds it and red if it cannot find it.  Using the simplest script

```
import sys
sys.exit(1)
```

According to the tooltip exit status 0 indicates passing the rule.   I assume anything else fails rule.   Problem is that the rule matches regardless of the exit code returned.
Am I using the wrong command to provide Hazel with exit code or is it bug in Hazel.  I am using the Latest (just released 3.1)  Have not tried on previous versions.

Comment: Instead of calling `sys.exit()`, try running a command that you know will fail, for example trying to `import` a module that you don't have installed. This will definitely cause the script to fail with an error. Check out [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) and just pick a random package...

Comment: thanks.  Tried that as well for good measure, but script still exits successfully - as with syntax error and divide by 0.  Reported issue at Noodlesoft.   Lead developer got back and it is a bug.  "There is a bug now with shell scripts. I am issuing a patch, most likely tomorrow so hopefully you can hold on until then"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug that crept in with Hazel 3.1 ... Confirmed from Mr Noodle at Hazel.  Works fine from 3.1.1 to current 3.1.1 now.

Just thought I'd complete the thread